# Preview doesn't show postscript (P.S.) characters

Tags: postscript

In my mac (running macOS Sierra 10.12.1) I use the default Preview to open the .ps files, including the .eps images generated by matlab or gnuplot. But my preview cannot show some characters or symbols in those kind of documents. For example, that's what I see on my screen, when I open a "ps" file:
[image]

What's the most possible reason?

Comment: Try Adobe Reader instead and let us know if the result is better.  Preview is not always a perfect substitute for the real thing.

Comment: Fully unicode systems sometimes refuse to recognize the old dingbat code page which maps everything to Latin.  Instead they expect you to use the Unicode dingbat range.

Comment: @TomGewecke I am using the .ps and .eps file to typeset PDF using LaTeX. The characters can shows correctly in the PDF, even though the preview still cannot view individual .ps files. That's kind of solution. I didn't try Adobe.